# What does "local -a foo" mean in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

Zsh manual mentions that option `-a` means `ALL_EXPORT`,

> `ALL_EXPORT (-a, ksh: -a)`
>
> ```
>   All parameters subsequently defined are automatically exported.
> ```

While `export` makes the variable available to sub-processes, the how can the same variable `foo` be local?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you might be confused on a number of fronts.

The `ALL_EXPORT (-a)` setting is for `setopt`, not `local`. To flag a variable for export with `local`, you use `local -x`.

And you're also confusing directions of propagation :-)

Defining a variable as local will prevent its lifetime from extending beyond the current function (outwards or upwards depending on how your mind thinks).

This does not affect the propagation of the variable to sub-processes run within the function (inwards or downwards).

For example, consider the following scripts `qq.zsh`:

```
function xyz {
    local LOCVAR1
    local -x LOCVAR2
    LOCVAR1=123
    LOCVAR2=456
    GLOBVAR=789
    zsh qq2.zsh
}

xyz
echo locvar1 is $LOCVAR1
echo locvar2 is $LOCVAR2
echo globvar is $GLOBVAR
```

and `qq2.zsh`:

```
echo subshell locvar1 is $LOCVAR1
echo subshell locvar2 is $LOCVAR2
```

When you run `zsh qq.zsh`, the output is:

```
subshell locvar1 is
subshell locvar2 is 456
locvar1 is
locvar2 is
globvar is 789
```

so you can see that neither local variable survives the return from the function. However, the auto-export of the local variables to a sub-process called within `xyz` is different. The one marked for export with `local -x` is available in the sub-shell, the other isn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tested this code.

    function foo {
        local -a bar
     bar=42
     zsh -c "echo bar is $bar"
    }

    foo
.it returns
> bar is 42
.
So in the sub-processes, variable `bar` act as a normal exported global variable?

Comment: @Zifei, see my update, it's `local -x` for exporting, `setopt -a` for `ALLEXPORT` (you probably don't want that on, it's better to keep namespaces as clean as possible).

Comment: What a mistake I just made. Thank you, paxdiablo.

Comment: No probs. One other thing - I don't think bar _is_ being exported. Your argument `$bar` in `"echo bar is $bar"` is being interpreted in the _current_ shell, not the sub-shell. That subshell is getting `"echo bar is 42"` and acting on that.

Answer (score 17):

In `local -a`, the `-a` has the same meaning as it does for `typeset`:

> -a
>      The names refer to array parameters.  An array  parameter
>                        may be created this way, but it may not be assigned to in
>                        the typeset statement.  When displaying, both normal  and
>                        associative arrays are shown.

Comment: This is what I really wanted to know.